# Campagnolo 12s with Shimano Cassette

Tags: compatibility, campagnolo, 12-speed

I'm considering building up a bike with a Campagnolo 12 speed mechanical groupset with a Shimano cassette.

I've been using Campagnolo 11 speed with a KMC chain and non-campy cassettes without any problems for a long time. I would prefer to use non-campy cassettes again for the 12s setup, as Shimano 11 speed hubs are compatible with 12 speed cassettes, meaning I wouldn't have to replace them.

Does anyone have any experience running 12 speed Campagnolo with Shimano 12 speed cassettes?

Comment: I tried comparing cassette spacing between the Shimano 12-speed road cassettes and Campy 12-speed cassettes. I assumed (!) that Shimano and SRAM cassettes are interchangeable, and based on this website http://obike.dk/teknisk_info there is a difference between the SRAM and Campagnolo cassettes. But then I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ha3lalBRCHI where the conclusion is that even the SRAM-Shimano compatibility is questionable. This is a non-answer but what I've seen so far implies compatibility woes across all 3 manufacturers' lines.

Comment: @jayded-bee thanks for that video link. I'm not surprised the Sram cassette didn't work well with Di2, because of the 10T cog and electronic system. This isn't an issue for mechanical Campy/Shimano though, so I'm more hopeful it might work. But still good to know!

Comment: Curious if you got an answer to this? I’m considering the same thing. I’m assuming it would work since 11 speed shimano cassette and chain will work with 11 speed Campagnolo. I am assuming that because the space is the same.

Comment: @HarryURanus unfortunately I didn't get a definitive answer from anyone who has actually tried it

Answer (score 4):

I have set this up recently and now have ~250km with an Ultegra 12sp cassette, Campagnolo Record chain, and Campagnolo Chorus RD. It does work. As this is the first time I've used Campagnolo (and 12sp), I don't have anything to compare it to. The shifting is a bit more...*fussy* than Shimano 11sp was and is a bit susceptible to over and under-shifting, but otherwise is OK.

Comment: Nice answer to an old question getting a dust-off.  This should be helpful.

Comment: I have heard from one or two people on a Discord server (for the Escape Collective) that this is true. As to shifting quality, my understanding is that it's fussier on frames with tighter bends. Also, a Shimano cassette would be better paired with a Shimano chain; that chain will be fine with an otherwise Campy drivetrain.